# Griffon framework for to convert a vanilla java based app

Tags: java, groovy, frameworks, griffon

I am working in a vanilla java based application which is also multithreaded. This project actually parses (more than 10,000 rows for example)large files(csv,xml,etc) and applies business logic and feeds to database. Thats about it. But there are lots of rules and not to mention data. And the way this project is structured is not clean.

I was thinking to use a framework so that I have separation of logics like controller/service layer/data layer. Is Griffon framework suits that? As I was just reading and found out people are using it to build nice gui centric projects. I do not need GUI. But again 1 hour of reading will not give me lots of insights. If anyone can help me with this.

- This project is command line based.
- No GUI needed.
- Lots of interaction with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the founder of the Griffon framework. The requirements you listed don't exactly specify the need for a desktop application.

Is the previous vanilla Java application a desktop one? If so then it may make sense to migrate to Griffon, specially if Swing was used -> migrate to JavaFX.

Do you need to interact with the data as it's being processed? Such as applying filters or moving data from one place to another, edits, etc? If so a desktop application may be a good idea.

Otherwise a command line application would work. There are many options but I think Spring Boot would be the easiest to get started.

Comment: Thank you! Yes this project is command line based. No GUI. Its my writing, I could not specify clearly. We have data coming from different sources and we need to precess the data as to our need. Such as now with the each data we are creating databeans(POJOs) and then after going through multiple processor(adding/filtering) we are saving the bean to database. I would look in to spring boot to.

Comment: @jillionbug2fix, maybe you have to look at something like data flow or data streaming: https://nifi.apache.org/ or https://flink.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

1/ project actually parses (more than 10,000 rows for example)large files(csv,xml,etc) and applies business logic and feeds to database

2/ build nice gui centric projects

`Griffon is desktop application development platform for the JVM`

Not a lot of information to suggest something

why not to try what you can do in one-two days and take a decision?

---

ps:

1 - sounds like dataflow component

2 - functions of nice gui not described))

and are you sure you need a desktop application?

Comment: Thnx for your answer. I do not need GUI.  Its a command line application. I will update once I make a decision about this project!